# A follow up question : compact sets included in a full, empty interior compact

Tags: general-topology

This is a follow up question to 
[When is a compact of the plane included in a connected compact with empty interior?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682069/when-is-a-compact-of-the-plane-included-in-a-connected-compact-with-empty-interi)

I realized that I didn't quite correctly formulate the question I had in mind, however I had a great answer to my previous question. I formulate this new question separately to be fair to the poster of the answer.

New question : when is a compact $K$ of the plane (with empty interior) included in a connected, *full* compact with empty interior ? Full means that it does not disconnect the plane.

Contrary to the first question where there was no "full" requirement, I expect that not every compact with empty interior satisfies this condition.

Comment: $K$ itself must have empty interior and not disconnect the plane, that much is clear. By a slight modification of the reasoning from the other question, we see that for every compact $K$, the set of connected full compacts containing $K$ has minimal elements. So the question is what conditions ensure that there are minimal elements with empty interior. Thinking.